# How do I build the JavaME jars with ant? and can i do it while running in javaSE?

Tags: ant, java-me, mobile, java

Hi I have source code that ant builds into a javaSE jar, and we ship that, ant also at the same time builds the source for a JavaME project.

which I currently then open netbeans and let it compile the jars for JavaME, i'd like to do this last bit in ant and wondered if its possible and if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, but you'll have to add tasks for pre-verification etc.

Have a look at

- [Antenna An Ant-to-End Solution For Wireless Java](http://antenna.sourceforge.net/wtkpreverify.php)
- [User's Guide for J2ME Ant Tasks](http://www.dribin.org/dave/j2me_ant/users_guide.html)

From the webpage of Antenna:

> *Antenna provides a set of Ant  tasks suitable for developing wireless Java applications targeted at the Mobile Information Device Profile  (MIDP). **With Antenna, you can compile, preverify, package, obfuscate, and run your MIDP applications (aka MIDlets), manipulate Java Application Descriptor (JAD) files**, as well as convert JAR files to PRC files designed to run on the MIDP for PalmOS implementations from Sun  and IBM.*

Comment: so that is for cldc applications, I'll have a look.

Comment: Is there any difference between this and CDC applications as our app is on the CDC base.

Comment: Can't tell for sure, but I doubt there is a difference.